# How do you properly empty a UITableView that is instantiated through UIStoryboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have a `UINavigationController` flow defined in my Storyboard file. The root controller is a list of users that the current user has access to and when tapped that pushes a chat view with the user that was tapped on. This part functions fine, the chat view controller is pushed onto the stack via it's segue and it loads the messages that it should load.

The issue arises when I pop the chat view and select a different user, when the chat loads it empties out the old messages from the other user and replaces them with messages from the current selected user. This implies that the view is persisting in memory with it's old data. I've tried setting the `NSFetchedResultsController` that backs it to `nil` and reloading the data and handling a special case for the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method that returns `0` if the `NSFetchedResultsController` is `nil`.

Is there a way to unload this view or clear the table data out between transitions to it to prevent the leftover view data?

Some code samples that I feel might be relevant:

```
// View controller that loads the chat view
// Not the view with leftover data
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *) didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedUser = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"userListToChatView" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"userListToChatView"]) {
        ChatViewController *ctrl = [segue destinationViewController];
        ctrl.recipient = self.selectedUser;
        self.selectedUser = nil;
    }
}
```

In the ChatViewController:

```
@interface ChatViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end

@implementation ChatViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [RequestConnection fetchMessagesForUser:[SessionManager currentUser]];
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
}

// Standard table view data source methods, fetching cell information for index
// paths and returning the number of items in the fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (!_fetchedResultsController) {
        // Create Fetch Request, Sort Descriptors and Fetched Results Controller
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

@end
```

And I've tried implementing a `viewDidDisappear` method like so:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
    _fetchedResultsController = nil;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

// And modified the numberOfRowsInSection
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (_fetchedResultsController) {
        return [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count];
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Which unfortunately did nothing to fix the problem. Each time I pop the chat controller and swap the selected user, doing the segue again, it animates out the cells from the previous view and loads in the current. I want (and expected it to) start from a clean slate each time.

Again: **Is there a way to fully unload a view that is instantiated via Storyboard (in a `UINavigationController` flow) or better method for resetting the data in a table view between pops and pushes of said view controller?**

**EDIT** I mis-spelled "disappear" in the code sample and apologize, the method was (and is) spelled correctly in the project and is being called (verified). Thanks @dietbacon for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provided a cache name on `initWithFetchRequest ... cacheName:`, then you can clear it by calling the class method `+(void)deleteCacheWithName:(NSString *)name` with the name you supplied originally.

I haven't tried this idea, but I think it should work fine on `viewWillAppear`:

Comment: The cache may be what is holding it up, when I get a chance I'll double check your method (which I've tried, but the cache was still in use then so removing it might be the solution).

Comment: Hmm.  If the empty results didn't work, I'm not optimistic about the cache.

Comment: After changing where I build the `NSFetchedResultsController` (in it's own function instead of it's getter) and removing the cache this problem has dissipated. I do believe it was the Cache as I ran into a similar issue earlier that day but didn't put two and two together. Thanks for getting me on the right track. I know this response didn't directly answer my question but I'm going to accept it anyway as the insight led me to the solution. Also note that the docs for `NSFetchedResultsController` urge you not to change the `fetchRequest` after you create the controller.

Comment: Glad to hear.  I think, so the next person finds this simpler, I'll change the answer to only recommend the clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
```

and not

```
- (void)viewDidDissapear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDissapear:animated];
```

Check if that method is being called. I bet it's not.

Another thing: I don't get why you're creating a property and using its variable so much instead of using the setter and getter? But that has nothing to do with the problem in question, just commenting.

Comment: Sorry, you found a typo in my code sample. Given that this is for a client project I'm working I rewrote the necessary bits outside of Xcode so I mispelled those in the sample but they're correct in the project (I just verified). I have also verified that the method is being called. In regard to your last point: The use (outside of the getter that I wrote) of the ivar instead of the property itself is feeble attempts at getting it reset itself. As I create the controller in it's getter it is necessary to access it via the ivar to avoid instantiating when I don't need it.

Comment: Ok, then I don't know what it is :/ Is the table actually reloading?

Comment: Correct, data is actually reloading. When it does this it animates out the old cells and animates in the new cells exactly how I coded the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods to handle changes. The issue though is that I cleared the delegate of the `NSFetchedResultsController` (due to my assumption it was playing a negative role) but it still behaves the same regardless.